# exec() php function returns an unwanted empty file

Tags: php

I am running a simple PHP script which calls a Python script using `exec()` in PHP to activate GPIO pins on a Raspberry Pi to turn (or keep) a light on or off. The script is called by cron every 5 minutes. It works fine, but writes an empty file with the same name as the script each time the script is run. The key part of the script is:

```
$command = "sudo python lights.py 0"; $result = shell_exec($command);
```

I have tried it like this:

```
$command = "sudo python lights.py 1"; $result = exec($command);
```

And I have tried it with or without `echo $result`. In all cases I get the empty file written to the `/home/pi` directory. The script is run in `/var/www/working directory`.
The cron script is

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/wget [lan_address]/working/lampRoutine.php >> dev/null 2>&1
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: what is the filename of this file? Is it `dev/null 2>&1` ?

Comment: Use secont and third arguments in ´exec´ cunction which stands for output and exitcode - renember they are passed by reference. Also ´dev/null´ are used most of the time to pass output of a command into null hole - which stands for enything what is passed there is nowhere stored at all.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the python script that writes that?

Comment: @coderodour. The filename is lampRoutine.php. The dev/null is supposed to be an empty 'place' where stdout is directed, to be discarded. I am getting an empty file called lampRoutine.php written to the pi home directory every time cron runs the script.

Comment: @apokyrfos. The python script does not seem to be the culprit. It simply sets a GPIO pin high or low, depending on a variable sent to it by the PHP script (ie 0 for off, 1 for on.)

Comment: I have found a solution.  The problem was with the cron script. If I run    wget -O - http://[lanAddress]/pathToScript >> /dev/null 2>&1     I get no empty file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution. 
The problem was with the cron script. 
If I add the argument '-O' to the wget command I get no empty file.

```
wget -O - https://[lanAddress]/path/To/Script >> /dev/null 2>&1
```